# Replace String using javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a json in a textarea `{"request":{"method":"GET","url":"/thing/1"},"response":{"status":200}}`

I have a function currently which gets the value from my textarea and replaces

```
    function setFontText(text) {
        var str=document.getElementById("urls").value;
        var res = str.replace(/"url":"/g, "&quoturl&quot:&quot" + text + "&quot");
        document.getElementById("urls").innerHTML=res;
    }
```

I am currently replacing only **"url:"/** however I would like to completely replace ( The Italicized section ) *"url":"**/thing/1**"* but the part in bold is **dynamic** here so I do not want to hardcode in my code like str.replace(/**"url":"/thing/1"**/g

Is there a workaround for this ? If the question isn't clear please revert

Comment: You should use `value` or `innerHTML` consistently, not use one for getting the value but the other one for setting it.

Comment: Thanks for the tip TJ, surprisingly the ans from Javas worked for me but if you seem to have a workaround for this I'd be interested to know that too

Comment: An alternative would be parse the json string to object and use object methods on it, then stringify modified result

Comment: No, just a side note about the properties you're using. I haven't checked it closely, but Javas answer looks roughly correct. (Also note that you're missing the `;` on `&quot;`.)

Comment: @charlietfl - I wouldn't exactly be sure on how to go about this, Do you mind explaining it please ? through an answer maybe. I haven't thought about this option

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the structure is consistent you can parse the string to object then modify that  object and stringify the result

```js
function setFontText(text) {
  const str = document.getElementById("urls").value,
        obj = JSON.parse(str);
  obj.request.url = text;
  document.getElementById("urls").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(obj);
}

setFontText('/MyTest')
```

```html
<textarea id="urls" cols=60 rows=6>
{"request":{"method":"GET","url":"/thing/1"},"response":{"status":200}}
</textarea>
```

Answer (score 2):

When you parse the json to a javascript object you can easily delete or alter properties.
After that just generate a new json from the object again.

```js
var json = '{"request":{"method":"GET","url":"/thing/1"},"response":{"status":200}}';
var jsonResult = JSON.parse(json);
jsonResult.request.url = 'newtext';
var newJson = JSON.stringify(jsonResult);
console.log(newJson);
```